# Update Model in the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I just started to make a new mvc-project. I made a calendar (on my own) which displays the days of a month. It has two buttons which lets u get `Back` and `Forth` months in a year. So my problem is I have done null Javascript for it. The logic is in the Model.

Now everytime time sb. hits for example the `Forth` button the view creates a HttpPost which should send the Model with the logic to the controller.

The controller should update the value and sends the "new View" with the updated Model.

Here is a little Demo which explains my problem more easier.
In this case I want to increment the (Model)-variable "Number" by 1 each time sb. hits the button. But I dont want to use Javascript. Is that possible.

Current State:
If I hit the button `Add` the variable "Number" gets incremented by 1, **only one time.**
Afterwards it just doesnt do anything. Somehow the model doest get updated back to the view. What am I doing wrong?

**Model**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Number = -10;
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyProject.Models.TestModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h4>TestModel</h4>
        <hr />
    </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)
            <p>
                <input id="BtnAdd" name="myButton" type="submit" value="Add" />
            </p>
        }
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public TestModel currView = new TestModel();
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Main
        return View(currView);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        model.Number += 1;
        //ModelState.Clear();
        //Somehow the model doesnt get passed correctly
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, every time you post the form, MVC will try to do model binding and for that it will create a new object of you `TestModel` class inside which you are setting the default value of this field as -10. So it will use that value.

Unless you change this field to a property with `get` and `set` , Model binder cannot set the value to it (from the posted data).

So change your view model like this

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Number {set;get;};
}
```

Set the initial value in your GET action as needed

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm=new TestModel { Number =10 };    
  return View(vm);
}
```

When user submits the form, you need to send the updated value of `Number` from your form again.Keep the value in a hidden field inside your form so that it will be available with the new value.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Number)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)
    <p>
       <input id="BtnAdd" name="myButton" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
}
```

Also, since you are updating the value of the view model, you need yo clear the model-state dictionary. You may use the `ModelState.Clear` method to do that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
{
    model.Number = model.Number  +1;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I just made the changes like u and Slappywag told me. But somehow still it updates **only ones**. In your case. The value is 10 and after clicking the button it gets to 11 and stays there.

Comment: I didnt touch the Index (POST) btw. Its still the same method

Comment: @manuchao You need to clear the model state dictionary. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using 
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)`, which will not pass your data back to the controller. Add a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Number)` into the form in the view and then the hidden value will be passed back to the controller.

According to the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for DisplayFor

> If the property is typed as a primitive type (integer, string, and so on), the method renders a string that represents the property value.

A plain string will not be submitted in the form, whereas a hidden input will be.